# play mp3 file in resource folder not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play an mp3 file in my res/raw folder.
But i get error as "error (1, -2147483648)" and IOException on mp.prepare()

My code

```
try {
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NavigationHome.this, R.raw.notfy);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also tried with

```
try {
        mp.setDataSource(NavigationHome.this, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.hipay_uae/res/raw/notfy"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Another solution that I tried

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

These too didn't work for me.

Comment: after the create() call, prepare is already executed, so you don't need to execute it explicitly, just invoke start() right after create()

Comment: try to initialize your media player before preparing it or setting data source to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help more if you can post the StackTrace in your question.

But, as per the information in your question, the below code should work for playing the media file from the **raw** resource folder.

If you use the **create()** method, **prepare()** gets called internally and you don't need to explicitly call it.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.notify);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But, the point to consider is that prepare() generally throws an **IllegalStateException**, and in your case, you are getting an **IOException**. So it would be worth checking if the file is in fact present in raw folder and/or the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your media player before preparing it or setting data source to it

Play From external directory

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folderName/yourfile.mp3";
mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();   
mediaPlayer.start()
```

From raw folder

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.song);
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String fname="your_filename";
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: It too not working, E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648) this is the error

Comment: String fname="your_filename";
                                int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayerd=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,resID);
                                mediaPlayerd.start();